# Event for web component "has loaded everything and drawn to screen"

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I have a web component which essentially encapsulates my app. Within its shadow DOM there are further web components (and standard HTML/CSS inline + external/Scripts inline + extenal) and those web components may in turn have others in their shadow DOM...and so forth.

I have a loading overlay which I wish to show until everything has loaded and has drawn/styled etc...

I feel like there should be some sort of event I can hook into. I've done a bit of searching which seems to suggest no, but given its evolving I figure things might have changed? If there isn't an event - how could I go about writing this myself?

Targeting Chrome 71 only

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. There is no magic event that knows when you app is finished.

To make this work you would have to supply the event.

You code would need to know when it is finished loading and then dispatch an event that can be acted on.

The problem stems from the fact that nothing knows if your code is finished except you, the developer. You will have to wait for each piece to finish loading and then, when you know everything is finished you will still want to give the browser time to render everything. So you would dispatch your event only after giving the browser this time.

You could do it like this:

```js
class MyAppClass extends HtmlElement {
  // The rest of your class is defined by you
  
  codeAllFinished() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('all-finished));
    },0);
  }
}
```

You would call the function `codeAllFinished` only after you knew your code was finished gathering data and creating DOM elements.

The timeout would allow the browser time to render things and then you would dispatch your event to let anyone know that you are finished.

Comment: How do I determine that my "code was finished gathering data and creating DOM elements"? Listen to the onload of all the supported tags here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp?

Comment: It is up to your code to know when it is finished. For example if one of your components requests some data and then renders the results, your code should know when that has happened. But this is probably a result of JavaScript running. an `<img>` tag can use the `load` event.

Comment: I think CustomEvents (by default) do not bubble, you have to explicitly set ``bubbles:true`` in the options parameter

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman : Regardless of whether `bubble: true`, events cannot cross shadow boundaries without `composed: true`, as well.